# android: Get instant current from NON-supported devices

Tags: android, battery

I saw that several android devices dont support BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW to get instant current.

Is there any way to get instant battery current values for these devices? If we root them?

Is it a hardware limitation on these devices or software limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most properties are read from kernel power_supply subsystem attributes of similar names. However, the exact properties, resolution of property values, and update frequency available for a specific device depend on:
>
> Fuel gauge hardware, such as a Summit SMB347 or Maxim MAX17050.
>
> Fuel gauge-to-system connection, such as the value of external current sense resistors.
>
> Fuel gauge chip software configuration, such as values chosen for average current computation intervals in the kernel driver.

[Official Documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/device)

Which means yes, it's a hardware/software limitation. It depends

Comment: thanks a lot. one more thing please .. 
Can, say, Samsung override BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW and hide their values (from developers) in their Android OS variant? or is it Android's core api which can't be software limited?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, can Samsung put a software limitation on the CURRENT_NOW property? such that this property doesnt return correct value for all Samsung devices.?

Comment: In my days of changing kernels, rooting and everything else. I saw that there is a kernel problem with Samsung's phones. The value was correctly showed with custom kernels.